# regex segfault when compiling with clang, possible compiler bug?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, std

let's start with the minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{

  std::string realname("My amazing string with trailing whitespace ");

  std::string ret = std::regex_replace(
      realname.data(), std::regex{"My amazing string with trailing whitespace ?"},
      "std::string" );

  std::cout << ret << std::endl;
}
```

If you compile this with clang:
`clang++ -O2 -g -std=c++14 test.cpp -o crash`

This will produce a segmentation fault.
Using `-O1` or less will work, using gcc works in all cases, and not passing the `char*` but just passing `realname` as `std::string` will work as well.

However the original code only has the `char*` so I would have to perform a copy to get the `std::string`.

So let's focus on the version with `clang -O2` and `char*`.

I have done some debugging and it seems to crash in the standard library regex parts.
To be more precise in `regex.tcc` line 501 reads:

```
return _M_pregex == __rhs._M_pregex
      && _M_begin == __rhs._M_begin
      && _M_end == __rhs._M_end
      && _M_flags == __rhs._M_flags
      && _M_match[0] == __rhs._M_match[0];
```

When stepping through a binary that doesn't segfault it will perform these checks in order and stop after `_M_end == __rhs._M_end`, however, in the crashing binary we will see it checking `_M_match[0] == __rhs._M_match[0]` first which results in a crash.

I'd be happy to get some input on this, as I'm not quite sure if I am missing something here...

But if not I would assume this is a bug in the clang optimizer, no?

Edit: clang version is `clang version 5.0.0 (trunk 296300)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the noise, after noticing that the provided clang5 on our system is as posted above actually not a release version I tried it with the release and clang3.9 and it works.

Must have been a regression during development...

Again, sorry for the noise!

Comment: I am hitting this issue in an optimized build with a released version of clang 3.8.

Comment: It appears to be a libstdc++ bug with large input strings due to stack overflow.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61582